# Express app doesn't find node_modules folder to load scripts from

Tags: node.js, express

I'm rather new to how webservers behave in general, so I have a few questions I hope someone can help me with.
It would also be nice if anyone could point me to an article or some documentation about the following topics.

Basically I'm trying to develop a webapp using Angular2, Expressjs and obviously node.js.

I have already successfully developed some basic Angular2 apps without a backend attached to it, which worked fine.
However, now I'm trying to send the index.html file (which contains a tag referring to an Angular component) to the browser from my server.

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});
```

You can find the html here: http://pastebin.com/utMHk8Pe

However, even though the node_modules package is on the same hierarchic level as both server.js and index.html, going to localhost:8080/test gives me a 404 for the node_modules script files in my html header.

**Q1: Why doesn't my server find the node_modules folder?**

Now, when I run my index.html file through following link, http://localhost:54720/testapp/index.html, everything works just fine.
Somehow it finds the node_modules at port 54720 but not 8080 (which is the port I made the express app listen on).

**Q2: Why can't my server find the node_modules folder at the port I make it listen on?**

As I've already said, I'm really new to node.js and webservers in general.
I'd be very grateful for any help!
Even linking me to an article which could be helpful would help me tons, since I can't really find anything since I don't know what to Google for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a static folder to enable this. Something like this:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
(...)
app.use('/static', express.static('public'));
```

This way, you will be able to serve the static files you need for Angular2, the ones that are present under the `node_modules` (angular2, systemjs and rxjs).

See this documentation for more details: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks! I wrote this middleware line for express in my server file: app.use('/static', express.static('node_modules'));
After changing my <script> tags like this: <script src="../static/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>, it worked! :)

However, now I'm getting a 404 for:
http://localhost:8080/app/frontend/components/main.js
I can access the file however when I browse to http://localhost:62217/testapp/app/frontend/components/main.js

Why can I access the file from the 62217 port and not from the 8080 which I defined? What is this 62217 port which changes when I reboot my Webstorm IDE?

Comment: Do I also have to define a static folder for that angular2 boot file? Seems so strange

Welp, I also added
    app.use('/static', express.static('app/frontend/components'));
And now it works, however it tries to load the js files without the extension? Like: http://localhost:8080/static/app.component.

I thought this config in my index.html made sure it added the .js extension?
System.config({packages: {app: {format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js'}}});